# How to add class name to specified Object

Tags: java, gson

I have the POJO that looks like the following:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
}

public class Opt {
   public int id;
   public String test
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC).create();
        Opt opt = new Opt();
        opt.id = 1;
        List<Opt> opts = new ArrayList();
        opts.add(opt);
        opt.name = "options";
        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = "John";
        person.age = 23;
        person.options.put("opts", opts);
        String json = gson.toJson(person);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

and I get the JSON looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 23,
  "options": {
    "opts": [{
      // how to add "className": "com.example.Opt"
      "id": 1,
      "name": "options"
    }]
  }
}
```

and I need to add to every options data `className`. 
How can I do it using Gson library?

Comment: you can add your own custom serializer to gson.  read the docs for examples

Comment: Introduce a common, non `java.lang.Object` class, and take a look at https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java to learn how to introduce a discriminator field to your `opts`.